# Doctrine :Unknown host when update schema

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I transferred my local project in One and One server, and I have a problem when I use console for update my entities. Here the error :

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H?te inconnu.

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H?te inconnu.

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H?te inconnu.

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H?te inconnu.
```

Config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "db59XXXX8X55.db.1and1.com"
        port:     "null"
        dbname:   "db59XXXX55"
        user:     "dbo59xXXXXX55"
        password: ""
        charset:  UTF8
```

Thanks to your reply and sorry for my english (i'm french)

Answer (score 0):

Host cannot be resolved, probably due to mistaken url. Check it with your hosting provider (this time 1&1).  Try first to connect manually with any MySQL remote software (MySQL Workbench, HeidiSQL, etc...)

Define your port, don't leave it blank. (Try 3306 by default).

Get rid of quotation marks, they are not mandatory.  Leave blank fields when needed.

It's strange to me that you would use a shared-hosting account with blank password. Probably you will need to specify a password.

Link to complete documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html